# How can I develop the in-site product filtering program with multiple dropdown using a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an in-site redirect tool for our E-Commerce site that I developed with the help of this site. I would like to make these in-site redirects with a JSON file with options suitable for existing links.

**The code I wrote**

```js
$("#find").on("click", function() {
    let mevsim = ($("#mevsim").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#mevsim").val();
    let tabangenisligi = ($("#tabangenisligi").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#tabangenisligi").val();
    let kesitorani = ($("#kesitorani").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#kesitorani").val();
    let jantcapi = ($("#jantcapi").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#jantcapi").val();
    let url = "https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf" + mevsim + tabangenisligi + kesitorani + jantcapi;
    console.log("url: " + url);
    location.href = url
});
```

```css
#find {
    background: #E8562A;
    color: white; 
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
#baslik {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
#dropdown-container {
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/6146/5961/files/summer_banner_2-2.jpg?v=1582620652) no-repeat center center !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    margin-top: -40px !important;
    padding: 80px 0 !important;
}   
#dropdown-holder {
    width: 300px;
    background: rgba(25, 18, 18, 0.4);
    margin: auto !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
}
.dropdown-holder .fo-info {
    color: #fff !important;
    margin: 5px 0 !important;
}
#dropdown-container > b {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-container">
    <b>Lastik ebatınızı seçin.</b>
    <div id="dropdown-holder">
        <p id="baslik">Mevsim</p>
        <select id="mevsim">
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=DiğerÖzellikler-4Mevsim">Dört Mevsim</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz">Yaz</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış">Kış</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <p id="baslik">Taban Genişliği</p>
        <select id="tabangenisligi">
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-135">135</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-145">145</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-155">155</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-165">165</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-175">175</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-185">185</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-195">195</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-205">205</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-215">215</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <p id="baslik">Kesit Oranı</p>
        <select id="kesitorani">
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-30">30</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-35">35</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-40">40</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-45">45</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-50">50</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-55">55</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-60">60</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <p id="baslik">Jant Çapı</p>
        <select id="jantcapi">
            <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-13">13</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-14">14</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15">15</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-16">16</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-17">17</option>
            <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-18">18</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <p>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/6146/5961/files/BDF3A4FE-49C3-4773-B17A-1CB340F33C14.png?13355" width="100%" margin-top="-5px" class="fo-info-img">
            <p class="fo-info" style="color: #fff; margin: 0 0 5px; text-align: center;">
                Lastik ebatınızı, lastiğinizin yanak yüzeyine bakarak öğrenebilirsiniz.
            </p>
            <button id="find">Hemen Bul</button>
        </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And,

I found this solution because the site needs a more specific application, but I couldn't figure out how to integrate this into the app.

I have filter combinations as a [JSON](https://json-parser.com/46c120b9/1) file that gives product results. Can we add filtering in order to select them only? For example, if we select the "Yaz" option in the first dropdown, only "Taban Genisligi" options of the "Yaz" option will be added to the second dropdown. Also, there is no need to assign values to each option in this filter option. If 4 options are selected, the button should direct us to the links in the csv file.And of course, in this case, we should use the dropdowns in order from start to finish and all selected. There may be exceptions because some filter options have 2 or 3 options instead of 4.

If you want to try it, the application on our live site also uses a way of working as I mentioned above. Our Site

As a newby software developer, I really need this development and I am waiting for your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var data = {
  "Yaz": {
    "195": {
      "60": {
        "15": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-195&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-60&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15"
      }
    },
    "205": {
      "55": {
        "16": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-205&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-55&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-16"
      },
      "70": {
        "15": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-205&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-70&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-15"
      }
    }
  },
  "Kış": {
    "185": {
      "65": {
        "15": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-185&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-65&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-15"
      }
    },
    "225": {
      "45": {
        "17": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-225&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-45&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-17"
      }
    }
  },
  "DörtMevsim": {
    "205": {
      "55": {
        "16": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=Di%C4%9Fer%C3%96zellikler-4Mevsim&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-205&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-55&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-16"
      }
    },
    "255": {
      "40": {
        "20": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=Di%C4%9Fer%C3%96zellikler-4Mevsim&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-255&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-40&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-20"
      },
      "50": {
        "19": "kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=Di%C4%9Fer%C3%96zellikler-4Mevsim&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-255&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-50&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-19"
      }
    }
  }
}

let mevsim = [];
let tabangenisligi = [];
let kesitorani = [];
let jantcapi = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  mevsim.push(key);
  $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
    tabangenisligi.push(key2);
    $.each(val2, function(key3, val3) {
      kesitorani.push(key3);
      $.each(val3, function(key4, val4) {
        jantcapi.push(key4);
      });
    });
  });
});

mevsim.sort();
tabangenisligi.sort();
kesitorani.sort();
jantcapi.sort();
mevsim = mevsim.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
tabangenisligi = tabangenisligi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
kesitorani = kesitorani.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
jantcapi = jantcapi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);

$('#mevsim').empty();
$('#mevsim').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
$.each(mevsim, function(i, p) {
  $('#mevsim').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
$('#tabangenisligi').empty();
$('#tabangenisligi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
$.each(tabangenisligi, function(i, p) {
  $('#tabangenisligi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
$('#kesitorani').empty();
$('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
$.each(kesitorani, function(i, p) {
  $('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
$('#jantcapi').empty();
$('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
$.each(jantcapi, function(i, p) {
  $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});

$("#tabangenisligi").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#kesitorani").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#jantcapi").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#find").prop('disabled', 'disabled');

$("#mevsim").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "0") {
    $("#tabangenisligi").prop('disabled', false);
  }

  let mevsim = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  let tabangenisligi = [];
  let kesitorani = [];
  let jantcapi = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key == mevsim) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        tabangenisligi.push(key2);
        $.each(val2, function(key3, val3) {
          kesitorani.push(key3);
          $.each(val3, function(key4, val4) {
            jantcapi.push(key4);
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
  tabangenisligi.sort();
  kesitorani.sort();
  jantcapi.sort();
  tabangenisligi = tabangenisligi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
  kesitorani = kesitorani.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
  jantcapi = jantcapi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);

  $('#tabangenisligi').empty();
  $('#tabangenisligi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(tabangenisligi, function(i, p) {
    $('#tabangenisligi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });
  $('#kesitorani').empty();
  $('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(kesitorani, function(i, p) {
    $('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });
  $('#jantcapi').empty();
  $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(jantcapi, function(i, p) {
    $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });

});

$("#tabangenisligi").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "0") {
    $("#kesitorani").prop('disabled', false);
  }
  let mevsim = $("#mevsim").find("option:selected").text();
  let tabangenisligi = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  let kesitorani = [];
  let jantcapi = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key == mevsim) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        if (key2 == tabangenisligi) {
          $.each(val2, function(key3, val3) {
            kesitorani.push(key3);
            $.each(val3, function(key4, val4) {
              jantcapi.push(key4);
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
  kesitorani.sort();
  jantcapi.sort();
  kesitorani = kesitorani.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
  jantcapi = jantcapi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);

  $('#kesitorani').empty();
  $('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(kesitorani, function(i, p) {
    $('#kesitorani').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });
  $('#jantcapi').empty();
  $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(jantcapi, function(i, p) {
    $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });

});

$("#kesitorani").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "0") {
    $("#jantcapi").prop('disabled', false);
  }
  let mevsim = $("#mevsim").find("option:selected").text();
  let tabangenisligi = $("#tabangenisligi").find("option:selected").text();
  let kesitorani = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  let jantcapi = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key == mevsim) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        if (key2 == tabangenisligi) {
          $.each(val2, function(key3, val3) {
            if (key3 == kesitorani) {
              $.each(val3, function(key4, val4) {
                jantcapi.push(key4);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
  jantcapi.sort();
  jantcapi = jantcapi.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);

  $('#jantcapi').empty();
  $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("Seçiniz"));
  $.each(jantcapi, function(i, p) {
    $('#jantcapi').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
  });

});

$("#jantcapi").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "0") {
    $("#find").prop('disabled', false);
  }
});


$("#find").on("click", function() {
  let mevsim = $("#mevsim").val();
  let tabangenisligi = $("#tabangenisligi").val();
  let kesitorani = $("#kesitorani").val();
  let jantcapi = $("#jantcapi").val();
  let newUrl;

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key == mevsim) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        if (key2 == tabangenisligi) {
          $.each(val2, function(key3, val3) {
            if (key3 == kesitorani) {
              $.each(val3, function(key4, val4) {
                if (key4 == jantcapi) {
                  newUrl = val4;
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  console.log(newUrl);
  /* location.href= url */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-container">
  <b>Lastik ebatınızı seçin.</b>
  <div id="dropdown-holder">
    <p id="baslik">Mevsim</p>
    <select id="mevsim">
    </select><br /><br />
    <p id="baslik">Taban Genişliği</p>
    <select id="tabangenisligi">
    </select><br /><br />
    <p id="baslik">Kesit Oranı</p>
    <select id="kesitorani">
    </select><br /><br />
    <p id="baslik">Jant Çapı</p>
    <select id="jantcapi">
    </select><br /><br />
    <button id="find">
      Hemen Bul
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Comment: Hello Matthias,
Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly. I just want to ask a few questions.
1. As you can see in SS, when we go back to the previous page after using the tool, the first choice is there but it is not working. It forces you to select "Select" (Select) and then choose the season again. https://gyazo.com/dd0d9efa9cef529b45bba48f6fdb72d6
2. Also how do I select certain values at the beginning of the page. When we got the values from the HTML code, I could do this with selected = "selected" but now I can't figure out how.

Comment: You can review the tool here. https://z9a7esnbvstyc9jk-25161465961.shopifypreview.com

Comment: Hello @BerkB. I can't recreate the issue with the first choice not working after going back. I checked at the provided link and it worked without any problem. For the "selected" question, I adjusted the code here https://codepen.io/matthias_h/pen/PoZYvdV (lines 94-101) by adding a variable selected with the value ["Yaz", "195", "60", "15"] as an example. If this would be ok, it's necessary to adjust the code further because the "Find now" button is then enabled when someone changes the selection again.

Comment: Hello Matthias, I want to talk about a problem I encountered today. When I try to change 16 of the Summer 205 55 16 options that are marked specially since the site is opened, all the options of "Rim Diameter" are not the filtered options. The options that should normally come are only: https://gyazo.com/2b8d955c65bd17749f40617df555ccdf

But the options that come are: https://gyazo.com/cd25d74324bbe645dccf18803441cf9f

How can we solve this? By solving this I want to provide a better experience for customers.

Tool Preview: https://3i2hn035j477ux8x-25161465961.shopifypreview.com/

Comment: It also happens in options 2 and 3. They were supposed to be filtered, but when I look at the options, I can select them all.

I look forward to your return, thanks and best regards.

Comment: @BerkB. Hi Berk, this is solved here: https://codepen.io/matthias_h/pen/vYLEPyr by triggering change events on the selects after each option is selected.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: @BerkB. Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final dropdown in-site linking tool. Thank you for your help, especially Matthias.

```
`https://codepen.io/berkb-the-scripter/pen/yLeLOVm`
```